# ldconfig is not seeing custom library

Tags: c++, linker, shared, ubuntu-11.10

We created a custom shared library from some C++ code using

```
g++ -c -fPIC customTest.cpp

g++ -shared -o libcustomTest.so customTest.o
```

And we put it in the project directory and in our makefile we have the default target being

```
main: main.o
    nvcc $^ -o main -lcustomTest -L.
```

And this works just fine.

The problem is, we'd like to move our library to `/usr/lib/` or any arbitrary folder and still have the program locate it and use it but this hasn't been happening as we want it to.

We have a folder in our root that we created called `libTest` and in that folder we put our library `customTest.so.0.1`. Then we edited `ld.so.conf` in `/etc/` to had `/libTest` in it.

Then we went to the directory of our program files and ran
`ldconfig -v`

which looked like this but larger

```
libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.9
libt1.so.5 -> libt1.so.5.1.2
libbluetooth.so.3 -> libbluetooth.so.3.11.4
libgck-1.so.0 -> libgck-1.so.0.0.0
libdca.so.0 -> libdca.so.0.0.0
```

a lot of links are created and what not, but `libcustomTest.so` is not one of them. Not surprisingly, when we run make the custom library can't be located.

Can anyone point us in the right direction with what we are doing wrong? By the way we are on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

> g++ -shared -o libcustomTest.so customTest.o

This will create a shared library with `SONAME` not set.

> We have a folder in our root that we created called libTest and in that folder we put our library customTest.so.0.1

Don't do that. Just copy libcustomTest.so into /libTest, and be done with it.

> a lot of links are created and what not, but libcustomTest.so is not one of them.

That's expected result. `ldconfig` creates symlinks from `SONAME` to actual implementation binary. Since you didn't set `SONAME`, no symlink for you.

Unless you *understand* what `SONAME` is for, don't bother setting it (via `-Wl,--soname=...` flag) either. On Linux, `SONAME` and external library versioning is usually the wrong answer, as symbol versioning provides much better approach anyway.